# how to mine ethereum on ubuntu

Tags: ethereum

I want to mine Ethereum without joining a mining group.  I have a Precision T3400 with a NVidia card,  running Ubuntu 14.04.  I am told this machine is weak compared to others out there.  I want to know how to set up my machine to mine Ethereum.  Perhaps later I get something stronger,  but I must see the procedure running well before I spend.

Answer (score 0):

you need to install ethereum client library like GETH. GETH provide CLI based user interface to interact with mannet. create account , mine ETH and can also perform transaction. i will provide you link of ethereum github repository.
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum